# Why was my post about Windows 3.1 icons found in Windows 7 placed on hold?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, on-hold, post-notice

I have a question about my Super User post: [Why are there Windows 3.1 icons in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/1200807/why-are-there-windows-3-1-icons-in-windows-7)

I recently posted a question about icons I had located in C:\Windows\System32\MorIcons.Dll. Almost as soon as I had posted it, it had been placed on hold for being 'opinion-based.' While I have held a Stack Exchange account for a while now, I am still confused about why some of my questions are placed on hold or voted down. I reviewed the help center documentation about on hold questions, and I do not think I am in violation. If anyone could tell me what I can do to improve my question or what I did wrong, that would be greatly appreciated. 
 Thanks.

Comment: Your question is opinion based as it can only be answered by Microsoft.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for your swift response. I appreciate the constructive criticism. I wasn't even expecting for you personally to respond.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you asked "**why**".

**Why** can only be answered by the people who made the decision being questioned.

**Why** is not an appropriate question, most of the time, in a tech-support Q-and-A context.

While we can guess as to the reasons (and there were comments enough on your post doing precisely this) these legacy icons remain, we cannot actually state with authority all of the real reasons.

Therefore, in the limits of the context of Super User, this question cannot be answered except by opinion, and then who is to judge who is right, and therefore how can we truly say **THIS** is the answer and **THAT** is not?

Except for certain specific types of questions, **WHY** questions will be closed for opinion, breadth, or other reasons here. The better sorts of questions for Super User are **HOW** questions.

Comment: *Why is not an appropriate question, most of the time*...a legitimate exception to this rule IMHO is a case where authoritative information has been published and can be cited by an answer.

Comment: That would be a valid question, though it gets close to missing the do your homework first" requirement as well.